# What is the syntax for querying in Python?

Tags: python, sqlite, python-2.6

I sort of understand how this works, but I get lost after the `WHERE`. Please tell me what is wrong with the following and help me understand what it's doing in general:

```
myVariable = cursor.execute("SELECT TARGET_.*, TARGET_, SOFTWARE_TARGET_ WHERE"
                           "SOFTWARE_TARGET_.SOFTWARE1=%(sw_ID)s AND"
                           "SOFTWARE_TARGET_.TARGET2=TARGET_.ID", sw_ID=sw_ID))
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
OperationalError: near "%": syntax error
```

Comment: It looks like you have an extra parenthesis at the end.

Comment: Please don't update your question when your problem is solved, only to ask a new question with the new syntax.

Comment: @AdamSmith Does this not count as the same problem? The updated code gave me the same exact error. Seems a bit *excessive* to ask this question over again. It will be nearly an exact copy.

Comment: @Kimbluey but the code you updated to invalidated Martijn's answer. The problem in the code you posted is definitely that it was missing whitespace. If you're still getting an error, comment to reflect that but don't change your question

Comment: @AdamSmith So can I leave everything currently in my question be, but add the update at the end for further clarification/to receive the final answer I am seeking?

Comment: @Kimbluey yes that way the next person that's having the same problem you are (either the lack of whitespace in the concat or whatever the cause of your other issue is -- I don't see it offhand) can find the answer they need.

Comment: @Kimbluey your problem now is that you've done `sw_id==sw_id`, which is `True` rather than passing some value as a kwarg. Since that's not what you've said you did in the edit I rolled back from, I'm concerned that the REAL reason you're getting this error isn't present in your question because you've copied your code poorly. Please *triple-* and *quadruple-check* your work

Comment: @martineau that's never a reason to close a question. Judge a question by usefulness to others with the same problem instead.

Comment: @Martijn: I think it's a valid reason if the OP basically works around the issue using some unspecified technique, so if any of the solutions presented would have solved the problem will likely remain unknown — which was the situation when I voted to close. However, since the OP has now reverted her question and confirmed your solution fixed it, I've revoked my close vote.

Comment: @martineau Then that should have been the initial reasoning behind your vote. In the future, please voice your concerns **before** deciding to vote to close a question to give users a chance to fix their mistakes. I'm new to Stack Overflow and don't know all rules yet. Please keep in mind that your actions have the risk of driving new users away from this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have no whitespace between the `WHERE` and the next word; the string concatenation doesn't add spaces. The same happens for the `AND` at the end of the second string:

```
>>> ("SELECT TARGET_.*, TARGET_, SOFTWARE_TARGET_ WHERE"
...  "SOFTWARE_TARGET_.SOFTWARE1=%(sw_ID)s AND"
...  "SOFTWARE_TARGET_.TARGET2=TARGET_.ID")
'SELECT TARGET_.*, TARGET_, SOFTWARE_TARGET_ WHERESOFTWARE_TARGET_.SOFTWARE1=%(sw_ID)s ANDSOFTWARE_TARGET_.TARGET2=TARGET_.ID'
```

It is easier to use a `"""` triple quoted multi-line string instead here:

```
myVariable = cursor.execute("""
    SELECT TARGET_.*, TARGET_, SOFTWARE_TARGET_ WHERE
    SOFTWARE_TARGET_.SOFTWARE1=%(sw_ID)s AND
    SOFTWARE_TARGET_.TARGET2=TARGET_.ID""", {'sw_ID': sw_ID})
```

Note that if you are using `sqlite3` you can only use *positional* SQL parameters using the `?` placeholder:

```
myVariable = cursor.execute("""
    SELECT TARGET_.*, TARGET_, SOFTWARE_TARGET_ WHERE
    SOFTWARE_TARGET_.SOFTWARE1=? AND
    SOFTWARE_TARGET_.TARGET2=TARGET_.ID""", (sw_ID,))
```

Quoting the [`sqlite3` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html):

> Put `?` as a placeholder wherever you want to use a value, and then provide a tuple of values as the second argument to the cursor’s `execute()` method. (Other database modules may use a different placeholder, such as `%s` or `:1`.)

Comment: @Kimbluey what database library are you using? What style of parameters are supported depends on the library.

Comment: I'm not sure where I can find that information...All I know is I'm using Python 2.6, ElementTree, SQLite3 *and* that the database is a **relational database**. Not sure if that helps answer your question. It's fine now though, I'm no longer using this code. Thank you for your answer

Comment: @Kimbluey sqlite3 is what I was after here; the library uses a *different syntax* and only positional parameters are supported.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information! I hadn't known about different style parameters for SQLite3 before now...So it looks like `?` is *always* used as a placeholder and nothing else

Answer (score 1):

Martijns answer appears correct - but your edited answer doesn't. Note that you're using `sw_id==sw_id`, which evaluates to a boolean and doesn't really make sense here. You probably want to replace that with `{"sw_id":sw_id}` (just like Martijn does in his answer).